# How to use the cloth modifier to make it look like the bottom on a stool seat (Stool Cushion)

Tags: modifiers, cloth-simulation

How to use the cloth modifier to make the top picture look like the bottom on a stool seat.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a try, it must be possible to get closer to what you show (especially the folds all around) with some tweakings:

- Create a shape like this, assign the bottom and top central vertices to a group:

[image]

- Give your object a cloth simulation, under *Physical Properties*, enable *Pressure* (here I've tested a value of 6), and enable *Custom Volume*, under *Shape > Pin Group*, choose the group you've created, under *Field Weights* disable *Gravity*:

[image]

- Play the simulation, then put a *Subdivision Surface* modifier above and below the *Cloth* modifier, give them a level of 2:

[image]

- It should give something like this, when you're glad, apply all the modifiers:

[image]

- Give additional sculpt if you want more folds (for example with the *Crease* brush):

[image]