# Modeling a Product

Tags: modeling

I got a problem while making a model of a product. I have tried a lot even seen lots of tutorial but did not get the thing that i want.
I am using Blender 9.92 and I am just a beginner I got my hands on Blender 7-8 days ago. I've just basic knowledge about I am trying to model a product "Mattress Topper"
[image: Mattress Topper side view this is the quilting] [image: Mattress Topper front view]

This is the exact look of the product, Help me how i can model this product and render realistic images.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of sending users to a link, add an image using the edit button. also add more details. what have you tried so far? there are many ways to create an object

Comment: maybe try this method (with Physics > Cloth): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224546/how-to-use-the-cloth-modifier-to-make-it-look-like-the-bottom-on-a-stool-seat-s/226581#226581

Comment: damn. I want to live in future too like you do. I am really interested in what Blender version 9.92 looks like :D

Comment: @Chris  ^^  or maybe we can talk with people from the future with this forum? that's crazy...

Comment: if you just got blender 7-8 days ago, maybe you should try following some basic modelling tutorials first, there's plenty on youtube (check the BlenderGuru channel for example)