# Modeling a Product in blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, blend-files, 3d-manipulator

I got a problem while making a model of a product. I have tried a lot even seen lots of tutorial but did not get the thing that i want. I am using Blender 9.92 and I am just a beginner I got my hands on Blender 7-8 days ago. I've just basic knowledge about I am trying to model a product "Mattress Topper"
[image: Mattress Topper front view] [image: Mattress Topper side view]

This is the exact look of the product, Help me how i can model this product and render realistic images.

Comment: If your question is closed, please do not ask same again.  [Modeling a Product](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227264/modeling-a-product)

Comment: it is totally unrealistic to believe that you can model this realistic after 7 days experience with Blender! Learn (!) the basics. Give yourself time! Set REALISTIC goals. Watch and learn from tutorials and build it and try to understand what happens. Start working! STOP dreaming. Nobody can do realistic products after 7 days of Blender. And you HAVEN'T tried a lot since you tried maximum for 7 days, right!?

Comment: If I would have the same realism as you have, my question would be: how can I do Iron Man III with Blender?

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible with *Cloth* simulation (and *Pressure*), if you don't succeed you could model this kind of mesh:

[image]

Then keep a low-poly version, duplicate, subdivide (with *Smoothness* at 1) and use the *Crease* brush in *Sculpt* mode to get this kind of folds (also use <kbd>Shift</kbd> in order to smooth the folds):

[image]

You can even use *Cloth* and *Pressure* to round it a bit if necessary at this step...

To finish, you can bake the high-poly to the low-poly, create 2 or 3 versions, duplicate to create the whole mattress...

Another solution would be to simply project the image on the volume, with an *Unwrap > Project from View*. Ideally it would be better to use the b&w folds picture as a *Bump* image but for some reasons it doesn't work fine in Blender, even in OpenEXR format.

[image]

Comment: You are totally right. But with 7 days experience I bet he cannot follow your explanation…because he would need a step by step with every click and input explanation.

Comment: You may be right but I wanted to give it a try, now at least he has a direction  ;)

Comment: Please consider i) going via the channel of editing and or voting to re-open dupe  question (currently one re-open vote  from @David) if you believe it has been unfairly closed.    ii) Adding [link from comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227264/modeling-a-product#comment383313_227264)

Comment: Ok, done, thanks

Comment: _*in future, in lieu of answering_ .  to discourage new users from re-asking the exact same question if their original is closed. (Irregardless of whether we agree or not)

Comment: sure, my bad  ;)